# Jquery select child of parent of anchor

Tags: jquery

I want to select and toggle() the child of the parent of the parent of an anchor.

This is an example of what I am trying to do. It doesn't work :)

```
<div>

    <div>
        <a href="#" onclick="$(this + ':parent:parent .inner').toggle();">hide</a>
    </div>

    <div class="inner">
        To be toggled.
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [`.parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) then [`.siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/), like this:

```
$(this).parent().siblings('.inner').toggle();
```

But, if you're able to make it unobtrusive that'd be a bit more maintainable, for example give your link a class, like this:

```
 <a href="#" class="toggler">hide</a>
```

Then you can bind that class (all instances of it), like this:

```
$(function() {
  $(".toggler").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().siblings('.inner').toggle();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){
    $('a').click(function(){
        $(this).parent().parent().find('.inner').toggle();

    }

}
```